# <ion-side-menus> not working inside <ion-view> on iPhone

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an application that at the root does not require any `ion-side-menus`. However, there is one view that does require an `ion-side-menu`.

For instance, take a restaurant. You may list a bunch of options on the home view (menu, contact, map), but when you click `menu` you move to a view that list options for breakfast, lunch and dinner. Instead of taking the user to a new view, you'd like to slide out a menu when the user clicks `breakfast` with all your options.

I was able to implement this quite well, using Android as my development target. However when switching to iPhone, the view completely stops rendering at all!

Below is the `ion-view` I'm using:

```
<ion-view view-title="Menu">
    <ion-content>
        <ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
        <ion-side-menu-content>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item ng-repeat="meal in vm.meals" ng-click="vm.onMealClick(meal.name)">
                    {{meal.name}}
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-side-menu side="right">
            <div class="item item-button-left">
                {{vm.selectedMeal}}
                <button class="button button-clear button-small" menu-close>
                    <i class="icon ion-close"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item>Eggs</ion-item>
                <ion-item>Cereal</ion-item>
            </ion-list>
        </ion-side-menu>
    </ion-side-menus>   
</ion-content>
```

And this is the menu toggle binding:

```
var vm = this;
vm.onMealClick = onMealClick;

    function onMealClick(meal) {
        vm.selectedMeal = meal;
        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleRight();
    };
```

Does anyone know of issues using `ion-side-menus` inside of an `ion-view`? In my real application, this provides an extremely organized user-experience, so it's something I'd like to keep pursuing and not change the layout to accommodate.

Thanks for any and all help.